# Contact form in a webpage footer is effective?

Tags: forms, contact-us

Are users really use footer contact forms to get information about companies?

Comment: Are you referring to links / information or an actual contact form in the footer?

Comment: Voting to close this because unless you get lucky and hear from someone with hard data, answers will be primarily opinion based and of low value. The answer to a question phrased like this is "it depends...". It depends on the site, the implementation, the reasons users want to get in touch, the availability of other contact forms, how much attention has gone into manipulating a users journey through the site.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends...**

Depends on the site, the users, the specific implementation, the reasons users want to get in touch, the availability and usability of other contact forms, how much attention has gone into manipulating a users journey through the site.

**The only way to find out for your site and your users is to test**

Make a hypothesis about where the forms should go. Track their use with event tracking in your analytics platform of choice, and the resulting data will be the answer to your question.